# Python Find Where Else Variable Is Used In Own Code

Tags: python, variables

I was wondering if in python there is some way to find where else in your code you use a certain variable. MATLAB has a feature like this and it has been very helpful when having to make changes to every usage a variable.

Comment: Depends on what IDE you are using. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python

Comment: It's not built into the language itself. I know zero languages where that's actually built in, because it's not really a language thing. It's all about the IDE.

Comment: Also, in Python, and most languages, you normally avoid having shared globals spread all over your code; instead, pass things between functions, or store them as part of objects. Then you don't even need to ask this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't a language feature, it's an editor, or IDE feature.  I prefer to use grep or other file-searching tools to answer these kinds of questions.

Comment: Some IDEs even go so far as allowing global variable renaming (for the terminally lazy and/or messy programmers - me, for example, as I've used this on occasion in Xcode's IDE).

Answer (score 0):

An easy(?) way to do this is to use 'ctrl f' and search for the variables, this gives them one at a time, though, but you have to hit 'ctrl f' again every time you want to go to the next matching result which is a pain.

Another solution would be Pyscripter (or a similar IDE), I used to use pyscripter when coding (not anymore) python, but it isn't great, and it crashes often, but it does however, have the built in ability to when you double click on a variable, highlight everything else with the same name, which is what I think you are after. I miss this as well, it is very handy.
My suggestion is that you could download pyscripter, and if you need to find all of one variable, you copy your code into pyscripter and use it for this only.

Hope this helps you. good luck